# angularjs ng-grid how to set row or cell height

Tags: angularjs

I should display an image in the grid
I've got this code:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'items',
            enablePaging: true,
            showFooter: true,
            enablePinning: true,
            totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
            showSelectionCheckbox: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex(),\'height\': \'150px\' }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>',
            columnDefs: [
                    {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id'}, 
                    {field:'firstname', displayName:'Name'}, 
                    {field: 'surname', displayName:'Cognome'},
                    {field: 'email', displayName:'Email'},
                    {field: 'address', displayName:'Indirizzo'},
                    {field: 'city', displayName:'Città'},
                    {field: 'zip', displayName:'Cap'},
                    {field: 'birthday', displayName:'Data di nascita'},
                    {field: 'joined', displayName:'Registrazione'},
                    {field: 'ip', displayName:'Ip'},
                    {field: 'url', displayName:'Prodotto',cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><img src="./assets/base/img/products/{{row.getProperty(\'url\')}}" /></div>'},
                ] 
            };

    });
```

all works well excepts of the image height (it is displayed with the row height)

I've tried with

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'cursor\': row.cursor, \'z-index\': col.zIndex(),\'height\': \'150px\' }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell {{col.cellClass}}" ng-cell></div>',
```

or simply put the style on the div img template

but it doesn't work
so is there a way to set the height of the row/cell ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's very simple if you know  ^^

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'items',
            rowHeight: 80,
            enablePaging: true,
            showFooter: true,
            enablePinning: true,
            totalServerItems:'totalServerItems',
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
            showSelectionCheckbox: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            columnDefs: [
                    {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id'}, 
                    {field:'firstname', displayName:'Name'}, 
                    {field: 'surname', displayName:'Cognome'},
                    {field: 'email', displayName:'Email'},
                    {field: 'address', displayName:'Indirizzo'},
                    {field: 'city', displayName:'Città'},
                    {field: 'zip', displayName:'Cap'},
                    {field: 'birthday', displayName:'Data di nascita'},
                    {field: 'joined', displayName:'Registrazione'},
                    {field: 'ip', displayName:'Ip'},
                    {field: 'url', displayName:'Prodotto',cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><img src="./assets/base/img/products/{{row.getProperty(\'url\')}}" /></div>'},
                ] 
            };

    });
```

simply add **rowHeight: 80**, to your grid options

Comment: The cells don't share the height of the row, they default to 30px

Comment: for cell issue, add celltemplate with height: inherit like this: cellTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'height\': \'inherit\'}">{{row.entity.id}} </div>'