# ng-grid wrap-text rows with vertical scrolling

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-grid that I am trying create a wrap-text column for a column that contains multiple lines of comment text. I have been trying everything today that I can find on the internet and still can't find a solution. I want to show you my code and if someone can tell me a better way of doing this that would be a great help.

```js
var vm = this;

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'myData',
  enablePaging: true,
  pagingOptions: $scope.GridPagingOptions,
  sortInfo: {
    fields: [],
    columns: [],
    directions: []
  },
  useExternalSorting: false,
  showFooter: false,
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'RequestNumber',
    width: 90,
    displayName: 'RequestID'
  }, {
    field: 'ActionByName',
    width: 160,
    displayName: 'Action  },      { field: '
    ActionDate ', width: 90, displayName: Action Date',
    cellFitlter: "date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
  }, {
    field: 'Comments',
    width: 125,
    displayName: 'Comments'
  }, {
    field: 'ApproverComments',
    displayName: 'Approver Comments',
    rowHeight: 25,
    width: 215,
    cellClass: 'wrap-text',
    cellTemplate: '<label id="approverC" name="approverC" title="{{ row.getProperty(col.field)}}">{{ row.getProperty(col.field)}}</label>'
  }]

};
```

```css
.gridStyle4 {
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top:100px;">
  <hr style="height:1px; background-color: silver; border:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:10px;" />
  <div class="gridStyle4" ng-grid="gridOptions" />
</div>
```

Comment: OK. I have been reading that I might be able to bind my column to an Angularjs textarea. I have been trying the following but can't get it to work:{ field: 'ApproverComments', displayName: 'Approver Comments', width: 215, cellClass: 'wrap-text', cellTemplate: '<textarea ng-model="vm" placeholder="{{ row.getProperty(col.field)}}"></textarea>'}

Comment: From this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116305/angularjs-ng-grid-how-to-set-row-or-cell-height?rq=1 I tried this: { field: 'ApproverComments', displayName: 'ApproverComments', cellTemplate: '<div ng-style="{\'height\': \'inherit\'}">{{row.entity.id}} </div>' }, and still no luck.